# DQL to find out current version documents in a folder

Tags: directory, document, dql, documentum

How to query folder and document both so that we can get:

1. All the subfolder documents.
2. Only the folder documents.
3. Count of documents in the subfolder, with the folder name.

Comment: And what exactly don't work for you?

Comment: For question 3, are you looking for something like an expanded tree view with a number of contained documents beside each? That's really hard, if not impossible, to achieve via DQL only. I'd recommend several DQLs and additionally some code.

Comment: I felt some joins can make out..

Comment: Yes, it could, but if you need the paths you will run into problems with selecting from several types and repeating attributes at the same time, which is impossible if I recall correctly. If you do need _one single_ query for all of this I'd suggest using sub queries. You'll also need some form of `GROUP BY` to get the count for each folder.

Comment: Ok thanks eivamu... I will post if i come across some solution...

Comment: It's not that hard to come up with the third one, one implicit join and it's there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took the liberty to name queries a bit differently than OP asked it, but it fits it too. It is just a bit more clearer what some query returns. I used Temp folder for this example.

1. All documents in folder including subfolders

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM dm_document 
> WHERE FOLDER('/Temp', DESCEND)
> ```

2. All documents in folder

> ```
> SELECT * 
> FROM dm_document 
> WHERE FOLDER('/Temp')
> ```

3. Count of documents in specific subfolders under some folder

> ```
> SELECT COUNT(doc.r_object_id) AS doc_ammount, fol.object_name AS folder_object_name 
> FROM dm_document doc, dm_folder fol 
> WHERE FOLDER('/Temp', descend) AND ANY doc.i_folder_id = fol.r_object_id 
> GROUP BY (fol.object_name)
> ```

Answer (score 4):

1. All documents within a folder and all its subfolders:

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM dm_document 
   WHERE FOLDER('/MyCabinet/MyFolder', DESCEND)
   ```
2. All documents within a folder *without* subfolders:

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM dm_document 
   WHERE FOLDER('/MyCabinet/MyFolder')
   ```

Answer (score 1):

All the subfolder documents:

```
SELECT r_object_id, object_name 
FROM dm_document(all) 
WHERE folder('/myCabinet/myFolder/', DESCEND)
```

Only the folder documents: I guess it's similar to the query above but without the `DESCEND` keyword. (I can't test it now.) (I'm also not sure that `(all)` is required or not.)

Comment: The `(all)` means it'll select all versions. Normally one would do without. `DESCEND` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have unique folder in docbase and you want to find documents in this folder

```
select * from dm_document where any i_folder_id in (select r_object_id from  
dm_folder where object_name='unique_folder_name')
```